# How can I show notification panel when swiping down

Tags: flutter, notifications, swipe

I am making a launcher in flutter and I wanted to show notification panel when swipe down on homescreen.

I am trying with flutter_local_notifications package but I cant figure out how to do it,

```
 GestureDetector(
     onVerticalDragDown: (details) {
     // how do launch notification panel ?
     }
 )
```

Edit:

Here is the example:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJBCF.gif

Comment: Do you mean a snackbar?

Comment: No. Notification panel like this https://www.sammyfans.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/samsung-one-ui-5-notification-panel-img.jpg similar to when you are on home screen of your phone and when swipe down it shows notifications and device settings.

Comment: If I am not wrong, I just took a sneak peak in the package, it is to sen the User some notifications. It has nothing to do with the panel. The Panel itself is the original Panel from Android. If you want to create a Panel for your App only, you have to wirte your self a Panel or use a library for it

Comment: Yeah I have checked it again flutter_local_notifications package doesn't  that functionality. I just want to show or launch notification panel of android when you swipe down in home screen just like in most of the launcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by calling native method through method channel

in your `MainActivity.kt` create a function to expand notification panel

```
private fun expandNotif() {
        val currentApiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
        try {
            val service = getSystemService(Context.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE)
            val statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager")

            val expandMethod: Method =
                    if (currentApiVersion <= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        statusbarManager.getMethod(EXPAND_METHOD)
                    } else {
                        statusbarManager.getMethod(EXPAND_NOTIFICATIONS_PANEL_METHOD)
                    }

            expandMethod.invoke(service)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Handle exception appropriately for your application
        }
    }
```

Then call this function through method channel

Answer (score 0):

--- First of all my comment as an aswer---
If I am not wrong, I just took a sneak peak in the package, it is to sen the User some notifications. It has nothing to do with the panel. The Panel itself is the original Panel from Android. If you want to create a Panel for your App only, you have to wirte your self a Panel or use a library for it.

--- Then to your second comment as an answer---
You are able to pull down the Panel from any app. I even didnt find any settings to turn it off. So to use/show ur pannel, just drag down from very top of your screen from your phone/emulator down.

Comment: here is the example https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJBCF.gif

Comment: Well This is possible on the homescreen on the App. I dont know, But also think if there is a possibility. Since also No one wants to Open the Control Panel in the App Screen